# Align R Shiny ggplot with background image

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I wish to align a ggplot in my Shiny dashboard with the background image of a TV so that it appears as if the plot is generated on the TV screen. So far I have been able to add the background image to the plot but I don't know how to align the two.

This is what I have got so far:

[image: TV background with ggplot]

The code for the same is as follows

```
     m <- ggplot(data_table,aes(x = centre_x,y=centre_y))+geom_point()
+labs(y = " Screen Height",title = "TV Screen ", x="Screen Width")

m+theme_void()+ scale_fill_gradientn(colors=c('#030C54',"#7c7DBCDE"))
+ theme(axis.text=element_blank(), axis.title=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        panel.grid=element_blank())
+guides(fill = F)
+stat_density_2d(geom = "raster", aes(fill = ..density..), contour = F)}
+geom_rect(aes(xmin=video_data()$frame_cent_x-video_data()$framelen/4, xmax=video_data()$frame_cent_x+video_data()$framelen/4, ymin=video_data()$frame_cent_y-video_data()$frameht/4, ymax=video_data()$frame_cent_y+video_data()$frameht/4), 
         fill='NA',color='red')
+background_image(img)
```

1. How do I stretch the plot to align with TV image width

2. How to reduce the height of the plot or shift the position so that it appears within the TV panel
3. If it's not feasible to tinker with the plot, how do I tweak the background image to fit with the plot. i.e. how to get the plot dimensions to modify the image dimensions

***UPDATE 1*** 
adding both ui.r and server.r code here

**ui.r**

Adding relevant portion of code

```
tb_dashboard<-fluidPage(
fluidRow(
fluidRow(column(4,
 wellPanel(
 fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("TotalValue_adj",width=12)) 
  ,fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("MedianValue_100",width=12)) 
  ,fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("Total_seconds", width = 12))
   ,fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("Total_score", width = 12))

 )
  ,fluidRow(sliderInput("sld_rate", "Avg. Rate per sec:",
                        min = 100000, max = 3000000, value = 1000000,
                        width='100%'
  ))


),
THE PLOT==>column(4,wellPanel( fluidRow(withSpinner(plotOutput('screen_exposure_locations')))
              )
   ),
 column(4,wellPanel(withSpinner(flexdashboard::gaugeOutput('percentage_gauge'))
        , withSpinner(flexdashboard::gaugeOutput('score_gauge'))
        , withSpinner(flexdashboard::gaugeOutput('quality_gauge'))
 )
             )
)
)
 )

ui <- dashboardPage( 
title = ('Data Analysis'), 

dashboardHeader(title = img(
src = "logo.png",
height = 50,
align = "right"
  )),
  dashboardSidebar(  shinythemes::themeSelector(),sidebar),
  dashboardBody(
shinyDashboardThemes(
 theme = "blue_gradient"),
tabItems(
  # First tab content
  tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",choiceRow,hr(),tb_dashboard),
  tabItem(tabName = "details",tb_details),
tabItem(tabName = "comparison",choiceRow1,hr(),tb_comparison)

)
)
)
```

**server.R**

I have used ggpubr library to add background image to plot

```
img <- readPNG(img.file)


output$screen_exposure_locations<-renderPlot({
m <- ggplot(data_table,aes(x = centre_x,y=centre_y))+geom_point()
+labs(y = " Screen Height",title = "TV Screen ", x="Screen Width")

m+theme_void()+ scale_fill_gradientn(colors=c('#030C54',"#7c7DBCDE"))
+ theme(axis.text=element_blank(), axis.title=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        panel.grid=element_blank())
+guides(fill = F)
+stat_density_2d(geom = "raster", aes(fill = ..density..), contour = F)}
+geom_rect(aes(xmin=video_data()$frame_cent_x-video_data()$framelen/4, xmax=video_data()$frame_cent_x+video_data()$framelen/4, ymin=video_data()$frame_cent_y-video_data()$frameht/4, ymax=video_data()$frame_cent_y+video_data()$frameht/4), 
         fill='NA',color='red')
+background_image(img)
)
```

Thanks

Comment: You can add padding to your ggplot2 image id as a css rule so that you can adjust positioning.

Comment: Thanks for the input. We are not very conversant with css. Could you please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: If you provide minimal example of your shiny app, I would love to.

Comment: Added code snippet in the question as an Update. Thanks